# Issue - "Next privilege" card overlaps on header while scrolling

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, privileges, overlap

Today I found a strange ugly bug when I was scrolling to my questions.

"Next privilege" card was open and I scrolled at bottom and saw that card overlapping the header. It is for all the pop ups available, Next badge, latest badge, etc.

OS: Ubuntu - 16.04 (Xenial Xerus)

Browser: Chrome - version 59.0.3071.86 (official build) (64-bit)

Zoom size: 100% (default)

If "z-index:1" added to pop up box, it is being resolved.

See the images below.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why bug?? The header is sticky. You can unstick the header via [your preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current), just tick the "Disable stickiness" and the "bug" won't happen anymore.

Comment: If the header is sticky even then the card should be below header. I can remove header, that does not mean it is resolved.

Comment: Sorry but I totally disagree. With sticky header, it must NOT hide contents. There is no bug here, it's working as expected.

Comment: Try adding "z-index:1" to pop up box, and it works as expected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems they have fixed it.

[image: Pop Up No longer overlaps on Header]

Answer (score 1):

This is intentional.

The z-index of the pop up box is 4000

[image]

and the z-index of header is 1050

[image]

The header should not hide the pop up box. A popup box and a light box should be above than all in a good design.

Comment: Try adding "z-index: 1" below it. It no longer overlaps header.

Comment: looks like another issue. I am inspecting it

Comment: You mean it is a "Good design" when header overlaps under popups? Really?

Comment: a popup dialog should be on top of everything else

Comment: Even if we can fix it? Even if it looks ugly?