# Recent names popup may overlap the top bar

Tags: bug, design, top-bar

Users that has changed their names at least once may see the "recent names" link in the Profile page and the corresponding popup with the list of names. Scrolling the page when this popup is opened leads to overlapping with the fixed top bar:

> [image: recent names]

Comment: Related, though strangely with a very different reaction: [Issue - “Next privilege” card overlaps on header while scrolling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299121/289905)